# Delete files with wildcard in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way which allows you to delete files with a wildcard in Laravel 5.2.

For example:

```
File::delete('foo/bar.*');
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I asked the question too quickly. When reading the PHPDoc for `File::delete()`, i saw you can give an array with paths as parameter.

So this did the trick for me:

```
File::delete(File::glob('foor/bar.*'));
```