# Delete wildcard files with Storage facade in Laravel

Tags: laravel, storage

Is there a way which allows you to delete files with a wildcard through the `Storage` facade in Laravel?

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('foo')->delete('path/TO_DELETE*');
```

I may have a list like this

```
path/TO_DELETE_1
path/TO_DELETE_2
path/TO_KEEP_1
path/TO_PROCESS_1
```

But I want to delete only the files. I want to avoid path manipulation as much as possible

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if you  have files start with `a_1.jpg,a_2.jpg` then

```
 $files = Storage::disk("public")->allFiles();

        foreach ($files as $file){

            if(Str::startsWith($file,"a_")){

                Storage::disk('images')->delete($file);
            }

        }
```

or for multiple folder search

```
$directories = Storage::disk('public')->directories();

    foreach ($directories as $directory){
        $files=    Storage::disk('public')->allFiles($directory);

        foreach ($files as $file){
          
            if(Str::startsWith($file,$directory."/"."a_")){
                
                  Storage::disk('public')->delete($file);
            }

        }
    }
```

Another way is using File facade.

```
File::delete(File::glob(storage_path('app/public/*/a_*.*')));
```

For example you have multiple folders inside `storage/app/pubic/` then you can specify like this.

```
app/public/*/a_*.*'
```

Here

1. First `*` is any folder inside public folder.
2. `a_*` means any file start from `a_`.
3. `.*` is any `extension`.

For last one i took help from this post
Ref:[Delete files with wildcard in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093634/delete-files-with-wildcard-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

The sub question here is how to get a list of filtered files in Laravel.  This works pretty well:

```
$fileFilter = "someStringFilenameContains";
$files = collect($fileSource->files())->filter(function ($value) {
       return str_contains($value, $fileFilter);
})->toArray();
```

You can modify `str_contains` (`strstr()`, `substr()` for instance) to suit your needs - anything that returns a truth value really.

This will give you an array of filenames that match your `$fileFilter`

then to answer the OP:

```
$fileSource->delete($files);
```